# Dropping 12V to 7.4V

Tags: voltage-regulator, adapter, 12v, nxt, step-down

I'm trying to power up my NXT Mindstorm Brick which needs 7.4V (at least, that's what the battery output is) with a 12V Power Adapter. I'm doing that because I want a constant supply from the socket without the need for a battery.

I have to use a 12V adapter because, at the same time, I'm using a fan which needs 12V.

How do I reduce the 12V to 7.4V or somewhere near?

I'm thinking of using a voltage regulator but can't seem to find any that regulate to 7.4V, if there's no other way, I might just use a 7V voltage regulator.

Alternatively, is there a way to step 7.4V up to 12V? That way I can use a 7.4V power supply, whichever works more efficiently.

Comment: How much current does your Mindstorm need and how much current does your fan need?

Comment: The fan is 0.18A, I'm not sure for the Mindstorm though, might vary since the Mindstorm is used to power up and control motors.

Comment: That's not much help since if you don't know how much current the Minstorm needs you don't know how much power the 12V -> 7.4V converter will dissipate, and you also won't know how much current your 12V supply needs to put out. Probably the best thing to do to find out would be to power up the Mindstorm with the battery and measure the current into the Mindspring, fully loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On eBay there are adjustable step-up and step-down converters for a few dollars a piece.

If your mindstorm brick needs exactly 7.4v (which I suspect it doesn't) and your 12v items don't need exactly 12v, then I would definitely use a step-up converter because it could be inexpensive and the adjustment would not have to be critical. It would also be quite efficient (my guess 90%).

If you need a 12v supply with a tight tolerance, and already have a stable 12v supply, then you could make your own 7.4v regulator quite easily with a circuit as below. The efficiency would be slightly under 7.4/12 = 61%.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhLPs9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I do not know how much current the Mindstorm draws, but the circuit above should be good to up to about 1A. It would not be too hard to increase with a few changes to the circuit, such as a second NPN transistor, or replacing the bipolar transistor with a MOSFET. (It may be necessary to find an op-amp who's output can get closer to the 12v supply.)

In the circuit above, for R1 and R2 you will want low-drift so that the voltage does not vary too much with age or with temperature etc. Also depending on how accurate you need the voltage, you may want a multi-turn variable resistor to be able to set the value more easily. However, then you may also want to take measures to increase independence of the 7.4v regulator from the 12v supply, as a dip in the 12v supply voltage (e.g. under load) will cause the 7.4v output to drop a little bit. The higher your requirements, the more complicated the circuit. This can be taken to the nth degree.